# React Native Navigation - Render a screen inside another screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen that receives props via navigation params...

```
function Comments({
   route: {
     params: {
       postId,
       postOwnerId,
       ...
     }
   }
}) {
   ...
}

...

navigation.navigate("Comments", { postId, postOwnerId, ... })
```

Now, I want to reuse this screen, rendering it inside another one, but I have no idea how to pass the props to it.

```
function Post({ postId, postOwnerId }) {
   return (
      <View>
        ...

        <Comments ?? /> 
      <View/>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Comments route={params: {postId, postOwnerId} />
```

that would work, but you might find it better to allow props to be passed directly to `Comments`

```
function Comments(props) {
   const postId = props.postId || props.route.params.postId;
   const postOwnerId = props.postOwnerId || props.route.params.postOwnerId ;
   ...
}
```

that will allow you to do

```
<Comments postId={postId} postOwnerId={postOwnerId} />
```